# Simplest/Cleanest way to implement Factory pattern in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

What is the simplest/cleanest way to implement Factory pattern (Not Abstract Factory) in JavaScript? Which covers following things:

- Performs repeating operations when setting up similar objects
- Offers a way for the customers of the factory to create objects without knowing the specific type (class) at compile time
- Which will work in all browsers.

I saw [Factory Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript) in Addy Osmaniy's blog but it does not covers second part. Classes should be predefined.

P.S. I saw answer in this question [Factory Pattern in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860443/factory-pattern-in-javascript), but this person asks about his implementation approach which is quite difficult to read and answer also suggests to use 'Object.create' static method which is available in ES5.

Comment: I'm scared you'll have to use `eval` for the second part ...

Comment: There is no other then `eval` approach?

Comment: None that i know of, if you want to implement a correct factory pattern. Matter is about referencing inheriters into the parent, and i don't think js is capable of it natively.